# Caliburn Micro Stack Overflow Exception using IEventAggregator

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am learning and trying `MVVM` using `Caliburn.Micro`. I have a main `ShellViewModel` and a Child UserControl `Module1ViewModel`. I am trying to achieve communication between both of them using `IEventAggregator`.
Now, I can change a property of `ShellViewModel` (which is parent) from child control ShellViewModel and can change a property of child control from Parent and it works.

**Problem :** Issue I am facing is that when I enable `events.Subscribe(this);` in both ViewModels I get an exception.
[image]

What I am trying to achieve is **TWO WAY** kind of communication. Which means I want to change some property of Parent from child at the same time I should be able to change some Property of Child from Parent. Following is my code, please check what's wrong here.

**Child User Control Module1ViewModel**

```
    namespace IntelliCoreMVVM.ViewModels
    {
        public class Module1ViewModel:Screen , IHandle<string>
        {
            private IEventAggregator _events;
            public Module1ViewModel(IEventAggregator events)
            {
                _events = events;
                events.Subscribe(this);
            }
            private string _firstName;
            public string FirstName
            {
                get { return _firstName; }
                set
                {
                    _firstName = value;
                    NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=>FirstName);
                    _events.PublishOnUIThread(FirstName);
                }
            }

            public void Handle(string message)
            {
                FirstName = message;
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, i am publishing and Handling a property.

**ShellViewModel**

```
    public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object> , IHandle<string>
            {
                private Module1ViewModel _module1ViewModel;
                private IEventAggregator _events;
                public ShellViewModel(Module1ViewModel module1ViewModel,IEventAggregator events)
                {
                    _events = events;
                    events.Subscribe(this);
                    _module1ViewModel = module1ViewModel;
                }
                private string _test;
                private string _firstName;
                public string FirstName
              {
               get { return _firstName; }
               set
                 {
                  _firstName = value;
                   NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=>FirstName);
                  _events.PublishOnUIThread(new CustomerModel{FirstName =     FirstName});
                 }
                }
                public string Test
                {
                    get { return _test; }
                    set
                    {
                        _test = value; 
                        NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=>Test);
                    }
                }
                public void Handle(string message)
                {
                    Test = message;
                }
          }
```

**Quick Watch**
[image]
**Stack Call**
[image]

Comment: @mjwills StackTrace is null in quick watch window of exception details …?? and in Call Stack Window of Visual studio it's huge List … how can i share that ?

Comment: @mjwills have attached two screen shots please check .

Comment: "TWO WAY kind of communication"? So when is this communication supposed to stop? There is supposed to be one publisher of an event . It may be handled by multiple subscribers. But if the subcriber publishes another event back to the publisher each time it receives an event, the publisher cannot respond to this event by sending another event to the subscriber. No wonder you get a `StackoverflowException` then. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @mm8 thanks a lot for coming ! Sir i'm just trying communication between child and parent ViewModels. And Can't a publisher be a subscriber and vice versa ? I want to make some changes in Parent ViewModel from child VM and want to make some changes in Child ViewModel from parent ...

Comment: Sure they can but they can't respond to the other's event by sending the same event in the other direction becase then it's gets new event back and the chain goes on like this until you're running out of stack space.

Comment: @mm8 i got your point sir . in my particular case just trying to understand. From parent some prop changed and published event > In child Handled and some prop changed + as child prop changed i published some event that then > In parent when handled caused some third property changed (now this third prop changed not causing any event trigger so process should stop here) ??

Comment: It's pretty simple: `Module1ViewModel.FirstName` is set -> `ShellViewModel.Handle` is called -> `ShellViewModel.Test` is set => `Module1ViewModel.Handle` is called and `Module1ViewModel.FirstName` is set again and it goes on in an infinite loop. `ShellViewModel.Handle` is also called when you raise the event.

Comment: @mm8 when `ShellViewModel.Test` is set => then process should stop ! i am not publishing any event in test property …???? oh yes in my question i am calling but i have removed that and process should stop but still same error ???

Comment: @mm8 Sir i have edited my question. Now if you please see test property change in Parent viewmodel not publishing any event. and process should stop here .. isn't  ?

Comment: `FirstName` raises the event which calls `Handle` which sets `FirstName` again...

Comment: @mm8 Now it's like . `Module1ViewModel` propert changed that published and event -> in Parent ShellVm this is handled and test prop changed (process should stop)...If we do vice versa from parent `ShellViewModel` `FirstName` property changes and published -> event handled in `Module1Vm` handled and changed prop -> this prop published event and changed -> test prop in parent (process should stop ) ????

Comment: `Module1ViewModel` is handling *all* `string` events including its own ones.

Comment: @mm8 ouch got the point ! it means whenever from where ever event of type `string` is published it will be handled by `Module1ViewModel` because it is handling string events ? am i right ? if so what's the solution ? i mean in many cases many `Vms` might be handling same type of events and if this happens it will cause same error everywhere …??

Comment: Define custom event types. Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirstName` raises the event which calls `Handle` which sets `FirstName` again and then it goes on like this in an infinite loop until you run out of stack space and get a `StackOverflowException`.

The thing is that `Module1ViewModel` handles *all* `string` events including the ones that it raises itself.

What you probably want to do is define different types of events so you can distinguish between them and choose which to handle. In the below example, `Module1ViewModel` handles events of type `ParentToChildEvent` but it raises events of type `ChildToParentEvent`. The `ShellViewModel` should do the opposite.

```
public class Module1ViewModel : Screen, IHandle<ParentToChildEvent>
{
    private IEventAggregator _events;
    public Module1ViewModel(IEventAggregator events)
    {
        _events = events;
        events.Subscribe(this);
    }
    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            _events.PublishOnUIThread(new ChildToParentEvent(FirstName));
        }
    }

    public void Handle(string message)
    {
        FirstName = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's clear and understandable now ! just one thing if you can please clarify to me. `ParentToChild` and `ChildToParent` are two types ill create and will use in this case. But if let's say there are two different Vms ..`VM_A` and `VM_A_Child` and i want communication between them then ill have to create another two types ? and so on for every different case. because if ill use  `ParentToChild` then it will cause `ShellViewModel` to listen .. In simple word create new ParentChild types for each new case ? isn't it bad ? and will cause too many Event types created in my proj ?

Comment: How many event types you should define depends on the logic of your app. You may certainly reuse the same type for more than one view model. It's just that you can't create infinite loops.

Comment: just one more extra thing if you can guide me calling PublishEvent from getter or setter is bad ??? or it's ok ?

Comment: if ill use this same `ParentToChild` type for another case or another `Vm` then it will cause ShellViewModel to listen ? and will again face some issue ?

Comment: It depends on how and where you raise and handle the event. It's the same as any other event and nothing special to the event aggregator.

Comment: i thought MVVM will make life easy :D ...by the way thanks a lot . i think i need to dig more about this and learn . Thanks for your time sir !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your VMs are recursively updating each other and self, e.g. subscribed to `IEventAggregator` and handle string message, than update a property and publish the same again, some kind of infinite loop. You can introduce a typed events to handle from Parent to Child and vice versa, instead of just strings

```cs
public class ChildEvent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ParentEvent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>, IHandle<ChildEvent>
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _events;
    public ShellViewModel(IEventAggregator events)
    {
        _events = events;
        events.Subscribe(this);
    }
    private string _test;

    public string Test
    {
        get => _test;
        set
        {
            _test = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Test);
        }
    }
    public void Handle(ChildEvent message)
    {
        Test = message.Name;
    }
}

public class Module1ViewModel : Screen, IHandle<ParentEvent>
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _events;
    public Module1ViewModel(IEventAggregator events)
    {
        _events = events;
        events.Subscribe(this);
    }
    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get => _firstName;
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FirstName);
        }
    }

    public void Handle(ParentEvent message)
    {
        FirstName = message.Name;
    }
}
```

Btw, you don't need a `Module1ViewModel` reference in `ShellViewModel` in case of using an `IEventAggregator`. Also do not fire events immediately in setters, because it can fire an infinite event loop between view models

Comment: So i just can't do vice versa communication of `strings` ?

Comment: Yes, try to use a typed events, like `ChildEvent` and `ParentEvent`

Comment: can you provide some example or resource help ? i don't know how to do that and not finding any help related

Comment: I can update the question with some example, but you don't have to fire event directly in property setters, otherwise you'll get an infinite update loop between VMs

Comment: ok . Ill be glad if you show some real way of achieving communication like this between view models !

Comment: ok i got your edit and understand it . Is it the standard way of doing communication ?

Comment: And i am adding Module1ViewModel reference because i open it in main ShellViewModel...is there another way of opening child usercontrol in parent ?

Comment: And also i dont see you firing the event ? how to fire the event if not in property ? like i did ?

Comment: This depends on your requirements, if you fire it in property setters, it'll cause an infinite update loop and SO exception

Comment: So from where i fire it ? i want to fire it when FirstName property changes …??